# Render view with overwritten getters in Backbone

Tags: json, templates, backbone.js, render, getter

I am building a small Backbone.js application and added some custom getters to one of the models (the name getter returns a concatenated first- and last name for example):

```
PersonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  get: function (attr) {
    if (typeof this[attr] == 'function') {
      return this[attr]();
    }
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.get.call(this, attr);
  },

  name: function() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
  }
})
```

I can now use `person.get("name")` to retrieve the name, nice. However, when I call `toJSON` on the the model these values aren't included (and I suppose that makes sense). Problem is I use this to render my views:

```
this.template({people: this.collection.toJSON()});
```

What's the best way to do this in Backbone.js? Manually creating the JSON with the overwritten getters?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just make "name" a real attribute?

Comment: Because I want don't want a static attribute. If I change `firstName` in this example `name` should return the updated name, I don't want to change them separately. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could provide your own `toJSON` method on PersonModel:

```
toJSON: function() {
    var attr = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call(this);
    attr.name = this.name();
    return attr;
}
```

The [collection toJSON](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.0.0/backbone.js#L622) just calls `toJSON` on each model:

```
// The JSON representation of a Collection is an array of the
// models' attributes.
toJSON : function() {
  return this.map(function(model){ return model.toJSON(); });
},
```

so adding your own `toJSON` to your model should work.

You could also add `name` as a real attribute and then adjust your model's [`validate`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) method to update `name` if `firstName` or `lastName` changes and to ignore any direct attempts to change `name` or complain about "an attempt to edit a read-only attribute" when someone tries to pass a `name` change to `set`. There's nothing that says that `validate` can't change the attribute object that it is given so you could be given `{firstName: 'x'}` and change it to `{firstName: 'x', name: 'x ' + this.get('lastName')}` before `validate` returns. This would be a bit of an abuse of `validate` but there is no explicit prohibition against `validate` altering the attribute set and it is the only hook you have. I suppose you could have the model listen to change events on its own `firstName` and `lastName` and then trigger a `set({name: ...})` but then you could have event ordering problems if someone else is watching only the first and last names.

Comment: +1 for giving all options, though i would not use validate to achieve this solution that just looks ugly :P although i love the first solution, just today i answered a similar post with a slightly different approach, with a toJSON() being called in a toFullJSON() method, stupid me, i could have overridden the default and just added the darn extra attributes :)

Comment: @Sander: I agree that the `validate` part isn't that nice but there isn't any support for virtual attributes in Backbone and there's not much in the way of hooks for setting it up yourself; constructor/parse/validate is about all there is if you need to do something a little non-standard. I'd say that this is an example of the problem with the usual "an object is a struct" approach that so many ORM-ish systems have.

Answer (score 0):

I choose to extend the backbone model and have all my apps models extend from a Base model which includes a method so enable setting virtual attributes which are merged into models `toJSON` method.

```
  toJSON: function() {
    return _.extend(toJSON.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments), this.getVirtualAttributes());
  },
  getVirtualAttributes: function() {
    var attrs, key;
    attrs = {};
    for (key in this.virtualAttributes) {
      attrs[key] = this.virtualAttributes[key].call(this);
    }
    return attrs;
  }
```

This allows you to define a virtualAttributes object on a model which can be used for retrieving a virtual/dynamic attribute.

```
virtualAttributes: {
  email_length: function() {
    return this.get("email").length
  }
}
```